# PYQT5 signals and slots design - one signal calling slots in conditional sequence

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have this issue. I would like to create one push of a button (signal) that gradually calls the slots (functions) after passing simple if/else condition. My biggest issue is that I have to push the button twice to cascade to the second slot and three times when passing to the third slot. How can it be avoided?
The first condition is to have a valid path and the second is to have a file ending by `USR02.txt`.
Any ideas?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QFileDialog, QLabel, QCheckBox, QWidget, QMessageBox
from os.path import expanduser

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(450, 39)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 10, 311, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.checkfolder)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Click"))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("Dialog", "C:\\Users\\"))       

    def checkfolder(self):

            import sys
            import os
            import glob
            import ctypes

            didi = self.lineEdit.text()
            if  os.path.exists(didi):
                print(didi)
                self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.checkfilexist)
                print("Valid path!")


            elif not os.path.exists(didi):
                ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Enter the existing path!", "ERROR", 1)          
                return

    def checkfilexist(self):

            import sys
            import os
            import glob
            import ctypes
            didi = self.lineEdit.text()
            fufu = didi + '\\' + '*USR02.txt'
            if  glob.glob(fufu):
                print(fufu)
                self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.abRunnormal)
                print("File found!")


            elif not os.path.isfile(fufu):
                ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "No files found, please try again!", "ERROR", 1)
                return

    def abRunnormal(self):
        import ctypes
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "SUCCESS!", "ERROR", 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: why change the function of the button instead of just calling the next function? `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.checkfilexist)` -> `self.checkfilexist()` and `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.abRunnormal)` -> `self.abRunnormal()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently connecting your button to self.check folder. What happens:
if you click the "pushButton" self.checkfolder is executed. if the folder exists you connect your push button to the next function (self.checkfilexists) which isn't called immediatly, but on the next time you click the button. Just connect to checkfolder and call checkfilexists:

```
if  os.path.exists(didi):
            print(didi)
            self.checkfilexist()
            print("Valid path!")
```

Same here:

```
if  glob.glob(fufu):
            print(fufu)
            self.abRunnormal()
            print("File found!")
```